Shape functions on the triangle using vertex values and derivatives
Is it possible to approximate a function over a 2-d triangle $\mathcal{T}$ with vertexes $\mathbf{p}_1, \mathbf{p}_2, \mathbf{p}_3$, assuming that we know the values $f(\mathbf{p}_i)$, gradient $\nabla f (\mathbf{p}_i)$, and the Hessian matrix $H_f(\mathbf{p}_i)$ at the three vertexes? What about an approximation of the integral $\int_\mathcal{T} f(\mathbf{q})\, d\mathbf{q}?$

What have you tried? Quadrature over triangular elements is a very well-studied topic in finite elements and finite volumes. Is there some aspect of the traditional methods that is not well-suited to your problem?

The quadrature rules per-se are suitable (for instance the ones from Dunavant (1985)). But to evaluate the quadrature I need an interpolation function. It's straightforward to do a linear function $f(r,s,t) = f_1 r + f_2 s + f_3 t$, where I've switched to barycentric coordinates. But it is not clear how to exploit the derivative information. A quadratic barycentric interpolant requires 10 coefficients, whereas I have 18 (3 values, 6 first derivatives, 9 second derivatives) leading to an over-determined system.

Have you looked at Hermite elements etc?

I've considered them but they require one extra value at the face.

For a quadratic polynomial in 2D you need $1$ coefficient for the constant term, $2$ coefficients for the linear term, and $3$ for the quadratic terms, for a total of $6$ coefficients. For a cubic you need additionally $4$ cubic coefficients. For quartic you need $5$ more. For quintic you need $6$ more, for a total of $21$ coefficients. A classical element that defines all of those is the Argyris element - it has all of the values you described with additionally the normal derivatives at the edge midpoints. A slightly reduced element is the Bell element where those normal derivatives are not specified - it is defined precisely with the data you mentioned by constraining the space to having cubic normal derivatives. For more details see this paper by Kirby.

Thanks. The Bell element led me to some interesting references, including some by Akima.

@IPribec They seem to have rediscovered Bell's element but didn't cite Bell. You can see this for the original paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/nme.1620010108

Apparently, the Bell element can also be formulated using Bernstein polynomials, leading to a more stable basis. Moreover, the integral is known analytically. See the work by Grošelj & Knez (2020): https://doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2019.12.023
